# How to find the WPS PIN for my Brother MFC-J6910DW Printer?

Tags: pin, wps, brother-printer

I am trying to connect my laptop to my Brother MFC-J6910DW printer, but I lost the WPS PIN for the printer when we moved recently. It is not shown on the printer or the original box either.  What can I do to get a copy?

Answer (score 2):

When you go to setup a WPS WiFi connection the printer should tell you the PIN to use via its LCD.

See page 20 of the Brother [Network User's Guide](http://download.brother.com/welcome/doc002716/cv_mfc6710dw_eng_net_a.pdf); "Using the PIN method of Wi-Fi Protected Setup":

- Press "Menu".
- Navigate to and select "Network".
- Navigate to and select "WLAN".
- Navigate to and select "WPS w/PIN Code".
- When "network I/F switched to Wireless" is displayed, press "OK".
- The LCD will show an 8 digit PIN and the machine will begin to start searching for a WLAN access point/router for up to 5 minutes.